# Hard drive renamed after restart, apps can't see it

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hard-drive, startup

I shutdown my computer when I left work and when I got home turned it back on.  When it booted back up the second drive (in the dvd drive bay) had a strange name like A[]\tr/sj or something like that.  My desktop background was the stock Mavericks background.  Google Drive, Skydrive, and Dropbox all complained they couldn't find their respective folders since they were all on the drive that got re-named.

I restarted again, same thing.  After the second reboot I just renamed the drive and restarted again.  Once it booted up everything was fine.

Any idea what could have caused this or what it may be a harbinger of?

Answer (score 1):

I would run basic permissions & disk checks, just to be sure, but it wouldn't be the first time I'd ever heard of someone [or their cat] accidentally renaming a drive by leaning on Return & a few keys, without being aware that the HD was selected at the time.

If you find no disk corruption I'd work on that assumption for now - but I'd also make doubly sure of my backup strategy, on the chance it's a sign of an imminent failure.